# CentOS filesystem size expansion?

Tags: linux, centos

When I tried to download packages from Windows to my CentOS VM it said I have insufficient space on my filesystem. When I checked it it had only 5.4mb left while I've set the VM space limit to 30GB. I'm new to Linux and don't know what to do. How do I expand the size of my filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short story (you *do* want to read up every step in detail):

- Enlarge Partition / Raid / LVM (in order of "loading")
- Enlarge Filesystem with resize2fs (depending on filesystem)

Resizing in wrong order might corrupt your filesystem or file contents!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have already used up all your space.  Do a **df -h** and see how big your filesystem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h
```

will provide you your disk space usage.  If you see that `/home` is full and you have space in `/`, then try putting some files you don't regurarly use.  Note: you will have to `cp` using `sudo` because you cannot copy to `/` with normal permissions OR   as root do the following:

```
cd /; sudo mkdir extra_space ; cd  extra_space ; sudo mv /home/yourUSERNAME/music/*.mp3 .
```

Explanation: Change directory to `/`, then with super user credentials, create a new directory called "extra_space".  Next go into "extra_space" and move as many as possible. mp3 files to this location from your home directory.

Comment: What if he doesn't store `mp3`s, or is really seeking to expand the size of his filesystem ? Also you're assuming `/` and `/home` are not using the same space, which is somehow a big assumption under a VM…